# Spring cloud override config in local (spring boot 2.4 upper)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

In previous `Spring Cloud Config` `Hoxton` by set `spring.cloud.config.allow-override=true`, you can override config in `localhost` `application.yaml`.

But in the new `Spring Boot 2.4` version and `spring.config.import` command, setting this property does not change anything, and config does not override in `localhost` `application.yaml`.

How can I do this in the new version? Is there any alternative solution for override configs to test in the local environment?

Answer (score 1):

I just added a new e.g. `application-dev1.yml` in addition to other yml files (in this case besides `test`) and I set the active profiles in `application.yml` as below

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test, dev1
```

It works for me