# How to set config server repo from different URLs based on application properties files using Spring Boot 2.4+

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a project in which I used spring.cloud.config.uri to configure the URL of the repo server according to the profile with which the application was running and had the application.yml and application-local.yml files.

But I needed to update the version of spring-boot to a version higher than 2.4 and it started to fail to load the configurations. Now I need to use spring.config.import.

What I need to achieve is:

When I run:
`java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar file.jar` I need it to load the configuration from http://localhost:8888 and when I run:
`java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar file.jar` I need it to load the configuration from http://mydomain.prod

I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring cloud override config in local (spring boot 2.4 upper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445781/spring-cloud-override-config-in-local-spring-boot-2-4-upper)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create an application.properties file with:

`spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://mydomain.prod`

and another file named application-local.properties with:

`spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888`

My mistake was not putting "optional:" in the application.properties file and Spring would not continue to look for the configuration in the application-local.properties file, instead failing immediately.